# ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 445513728 into shape (2266,256,256,1)

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, image-processing, keras

here is the code that i'm trying to run

```
labelled_data = [data, Label]
X,Y = [labelled_data[0],labelled_data[1]]

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.4, 
random_state=4)

x_test, x_validation, y_test, y_validation=train_test_split(X_test, 
Y_test, test_size=0.5,
 random_state=4)
import numpy as np


print(X_train.shape)
```

the output is:

```
(2266, 196608)
```

now i want to reshape the matrices for training set, validation set and test set.

```
X_train = X_train.reshape((X_train.shape[0],256,256,1))
x_validation = x_validation.reshape((x_validation.shape[0],256,256,1))
x_test =x_test.reshape((x_test.shape[0],256,256,1))

X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
x_validation = x_validation.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')


X_train = X_train/255
x_validation = x_validation/255
x_test =x_test/255

from keras.utils import np_utils
Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(Y_train,8)
y_validation =np_utils.to_categorical(y_validation,8)
y_test =np_utils.to_categorical(y_test,8)
```

while running tis i'm getting some error.

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-fc799feec008> in <module>
----> 1 X_train = X_train.reshape((X_train.shape[0],256,256,1))
      2 x_validation = x_validation.reshape((x_validation.shape[0],256,256,1))
      3 x_test =x_test.reshape((x_test.shape[0],256,256,1))
      4 
      5 X_train = X_train.astype('float32')

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 445513728 into shape (2266,256,256,1)
```

please help me out with this

Answer (score 0):

If the output of print(X_train.shape) is (2266, 196608), then X_train.shape[0] is 2266.

If you then say

```
X_train = X_train.reshape((X_train.shape[0],256,256,1))
```

you are trying to reshape 2266 x 196608 (=445513728) into 2266 x 256 x 256 x 1 (=148504576) so you get the message

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 445513728 into shape (2266,256,256,1)
```

One of those 256 values needs to be 768 to make that reshape work.